# Youtube embed fails to play, despite fully loading, Chrome only

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

My website http://goproheroes.com works fine in Firefox and Safari, but refuses to play recently in Chrome.

I see tons of XHR requests and no errors, the YT player just refuses to play, no console errors. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before, and in the other cases it was fixed by adding http:// or https:// in the src in front of your embed url.

Yours is currently `src="//www.youtube.com/embed/zvAgYeHAoic"`

Comment: I went to your site, viewed the source and copied it from there (its in the embedded iframe)

Comment: I've checked on both Chrome and Firefox and I can't find a single instance where it's missing the https or http. Both in code and browser view source :/

Comment: I looked again, you're right.  its http:, I must have hit 'get embed' code option.  Please change it to https: and see what happens

Comment: OK after some local testing, removing &enablejsapi=1 is the fix. Trouble is I need the js API. How frustrating. I'll see if anyone is having issues with jsapi on Chrome

Comment: OK so not sure what's changed YT's end but the issue was setting player.setPlaybackQuality() to anything other than 'default' was causing issues. Once I set it to 'default' it works fine :/